# Oracle and PHP - How do I use this Oracle Query in php?

Tags: php, database, oracle, view

I have an oracle database with a view for my department set up.

A sample query is below:

```
SELECT p.*,
    c.*,
    cd."ContactDeliveryKey",cd."ContactClassName",cd."AgentDistMechName"
FROM AVAYAIQ."PartyDim" p
    LEFT JOIN AVAYAIQ."AgentContactSegmentFact" c ON p."PartyKey" = c."PartyKey"
    LEFT JOIN AVAYAIQ."ContactDeliveryDim" cd ON c."ContactDeliveryKey" = cd."ContactDeliveryKey"
WHERE p."FullName" LIKE 'US_EC%' AND BETWEEN '24053040' AND '24053940'
    AND cd."ContactClassName"!='_Outbound_' AND cd."AgentDistMechName"!='_Manual_'
    AND p."PartyKey"='718'
ORDER BY c."StartDateKey" ASC;
```

When I run this in SQL Developer, it's fine. But trying to run similar code in PHP is proving impossible to me.

Oracle doesn't let me use SINGLE QUOTES (it seems to force double) on the table rows and row data has to be inside of single quotes.

Trying it any other way and I get errors.

How am I suppose to use a query like this in PHP since it has both single and double quotes and it breaks my variable?

Do I have to escape every double quote on here to get it to work? 
I apologize if this is a dumb question that is easily solved.

Thank you for looking.

Comment: Escape the double quotes: `$query = "SELECT \"foo\"";`

Comment: you can put this in procedure and run it as procedure

Comment: Note that the line'WHERE p."FullName" LIKE 'US_EC%' AND BETWEEN '24053040' AND '24053940'' will not run, its lacking a column name on the left side of the BETWEEN-operator.

Comment: Furthermore, is your view really using mixed-case column names? On Oracle this is considered a very bad practice by many seasoned DBAs and Developers alike. Having standard column names would remove the need to quote column names altogether.

Comment: cstotzer-I guess when I copied the code over, I messed up the BETWEEN. I do have a column name in there in my code.

Comment: Not super clear on how procedures work.

Comment: This is a view provided by Avaya. So, yeah, that's exactly how they are listed.